# How do i get prediction accuracy when testing unknown data on a saved model in Scikit-Learn?

Tags: machine-learning, python, prediction, scikit-learn

i have a model i have trained for binary classification, i now want to use it to predict unknown class elements.

```
     from sklearn.externals import joblib
     model = joblib.load('../model/randomForestModel.pkl')
     test_data = df_test.values # df_test is a dataframe with my test data
     output = model.predict(test_data[:,1:]) # this outputs the prediction either 1 or 0
```

I know how to get confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, classification_report given the training dataset, but in the case i do not have the train data.
i would like to get something akin to this from weka:

```
       inst#     actual  predicted error prediction
           1        1:?        1:0       0.757
```

Is it possible in Scikit-learn? if so, how do i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can only get the prediction accuracy on any dataset, if you have the true classes / targets. so in a real world application of your model to a completely unknown testset without classes, you cannot get the prediction error. the prediction error is derived from the true classes.

but you can use your trainingset and split it into test / validation parts, to get prediction accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your new test data has similar distribution as the used training data. Use cross validation to evaluate your model. By this way you can be sure that accuracy of test data matches the accuracy on the training data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have accuracy scores without the real values. However, you can split your data into test and training data to test the model accuracy. If the model is having good results, it will probably also work well on forecasting future data. When you have access to future data values, you will then be able to compare those values.